# Rollback and commit transaction SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a script which declares a couple of temporary tables and has cursors to loop through each item and then performs updates. However, I wanted to add a rollback to this in case anything within the script fails it can roll back, otherwise commit.

How would I do this exactly? I have looked at the other questions related to this but I am still confused. Thanks.

Would this work?

```
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        ----sql statements ---
        --- inserts-----
        ---- updates -----
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Comment: This will work just fine in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly your code will work fine:

```
OPEN CURSOR
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
           COMMIT
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK
        END CATCH
    END TRANSACTION
CLOSE CURSOR
```

However, why do you want to use cursor? as far as I know, cursor performs slow in term of performance and once your transaction fail and go to rollback, all of your transaction in cursor will be rollback. CMIWW.

Answer (score 0):

You could post your code but let's see:

If I understood correctly you want to commit  if your query runs without any errors, if occurs anything wrong  you want to rollback right?

You're using Cursor, you open and close  the cursor  in your script you could do something like this:

```
OPEN CURSOR

CODE...

CLOSE CURSOR

COMMIT /*it just will commit  if your script runs without errors.*/
```

If it fails  you won't loose your data.

Comment: Yeah as dodexahedron said  it will. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a [code snippet](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/scripts/tsql/code-template-handling-transactions-sql-server-rollback-xact_abort) to use:

```
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;

        BEGIN TRY
                BEGIN TRANSACTION
                -- Your script here

                COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
                IF XACT_STATE() != 0   
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                -- Re-throw error here                    
        END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with code structure you are following. You can just modify a bit like below which will work. so ultimately, if everything goes well (within `TRY`) go ahead and commit. If it enters into `CATCH` segment roll it back.

I don't see need for checking `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0`; cause since everything is within a transaction they will abide by the `atomicity` property. So even a single one fails for some reason; you should rollback (no partial commit)

```
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        ----sql statements ---
        --- inserts-----
        ---- updates -----
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```